# What do I need to install the front number plate on my car?

Tags: mazda

I need to attach the number plate on the front of my Mazda but I can't just put screws through as the holes are rectangle (see picture). I think it will need something in between but don't know the name of that accessory.

[image]

EDIT:
In fact, somebody stole my plate (on-street parking). For that I don't bother much because it was the old plate. I bought the car second-hand and applied for the new plate, which just arrived.
This is the plate before being stolen. It doesn't look like it needs something complicated/big/etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick google search turns up:

license plate bracket
license plate mount

Could get more specific with a year and model

Comment: It's a 2005 Mazda 6. I search for these but they generally look more complicated than needed (as in the picture) to get it hooked.

Comment: There will be a plate/bracket that attaches to the bumper, then you attach the license plate to that.  The plate does not attach directly to the bumper.

Comment: you may need something like this http://www.homedepot.com/p/Crown-Bolt-8-Square-Push-In-Nut-Nylon-2-Pack-53618/203537132

Comment: I've moved to Australia (i.e., homedepot isn't around), but it looks like what I will need. Thanks :)